# How can I take a map outline and lettering from a sphere and put it on to another exact size blank sphere so that they are both identical

Tags: objects

I want to be able to take a simple map outline also gradations and lettering that is on a sphere and transfer these onto a sphere of the exact same size so that I have two spheres exactly the same, the original sphere is in two halves and the other is the same, this has baffled me any ,thank you for any help

Comment: Hi Deleteme7777, welcome to Blender.SE. This question appears to be very unclear. Try adding some screenshots of what you have tried so far, and what your desired output is. Maybe you can find someone else's work, who has done something similiar and use that as a basis to describe your problem. Use punctuation and paragraphs please to structure your question.

Comment: Do you just want to cut a textured sphere in half?